# Determining Objective-C selector for Swift class extension function

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Given the below UIButton extension, what would the correct Objective-C selector be? I'm using an Objective-C library and one of the parameters for a function in that library is an Objective-C selector. I've tried a couple of variations on `#selector(UIButton.setBackgroundColor(color:state:))`, but I always get the following exception:

```
017-10-31 21:38:52.951949-0400 ExampleSwift[13161:2121762] -[_SwiftValue integerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000045520
2017-10-31 21:38:52.960430-0400 ExampleSwift[13161:2121762] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue integerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000045520'
```

I'd like to verify the selector and then, if necessary, start digging into the library to see why it's not handling the selector properly.

Here is the UIButton extension:

```
extension UIButton {
    @objc func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, state: UIControlState) {
        let image: UIImage? = UIButton.image(with: color)
        setBackgroundImage(image, for: state)
    }

    fileprivate class func image(with color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context: CGContext? = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context?.fill(rect)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image ?? UIImage()
    }
}
```

I'm attempting to create an example for using Classy in a Swift project. The project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/dnedrow/Classy/tree/master/ExampleSwift). If you want to pull and build it locally, you should update the Podfile and change `pod 'Classy', :path => '..'` to `pod 'Classy'` and run `pod install`. The part I'm having trouble with is in the AppDelegate implementation file, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function. See the `buttonClassDescriptor?.setArgumentDescriptors` call. Be sure to use the workspace in Xcode.

Comment: I could not reproduce your exception. Could you paste your code on how you call that selector?

Comment: that selector looks correct to me... may have to do with how its being called. I know UIControlStates are actually backed by ints: `typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIControlState)` so might have to do with that?

Comment: you can try adding an exception breakpoint to see if it stops on a more useful line of code for you to look at

Comment: I'm attempting to create an example for using Classy in a Swift project. The project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/dnedrow/Classy/tree/master/ExampleSwift). If you want to pull and build it locally, you should update the Podfile and change ```pod 'Classy', :path => '..'``` to ```pod 'Classy'``` and run ```pod install```.